# Create an xml file for dlib training

Tags: xml, dlib

I'm trying to create an XML file by exploiting the [imglab tool](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/tree/master/tools/imglab) provided by dlib. I have a dataset of 21 images each with a single face. I must affix on each 68 landmarks at my leisure.

The file created with my landmarks is different from the XML file provided by dlib : namely each record is defined as a single box and should be considered as a part of the main box with containing the face.

Help me!

Comment: To do it quickly and with the inspiration from dlib/imglab, I have created it's [web](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/imglab) version. You can use 3rd party libraries to determine face and landmark points on an img that you can save in dlib xml or pts file. You can also adjust the point and box to increase the accuracy.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are trying to draw boxes manually around every face feature instead of using "part selection" mode

**imglab -h** will show you this:

> --parts             The display will allow image parts to be
>   labeled.
>                              The set of allowable parts is defined by  which
>                              should be a space separated list of parts.

Try this:

1. Create xml file for some images directory

   imglab -c xml_file_name.xml /path/to/images/folder
2. run imglab with --parts argument:

   imglab --parts "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"  xml_file_name.xml

This will make imglab know about 8 features possible to annotate in box area

3. After imglab opened - draw box, select it (should be blue) and right-click inside - you will get popup menu for part selection

Also consider reading help/about in imglab for using instructions

After saving xml file you will get something like this:

```
  <image file='1\a1.jpg'>
    <box top='26' left='33' width='78' height='73'>
      <part name='1' x='67' y='68'/>
    </box>
  </image>
```

Comment: my problem is now the following:
I can train with a number less than 68?
in the case of strongly inclined faces I can annotate my images with only visible landmarks? I would have problems in the process of training?

Comment: you mean some faces will have 68 and other 67 featuers (example) ?
or you want to train all faces with 30 features?

Comment: if i have some images with 30 annotation but from other images inclination is so accentuated that it can not enter all 30 landmarks, but only few of these, is this a problem for train?

Comment: dlib has a code to exclude missing features from training, but not from predicting. With my experience it is not recommended to exlude any features from training because shapre_predictor will return all feature list every time it will be called. I recommend you to put all features to every image (even if they evrlap with other features) because it will be the way how dlib will return you the result. if the feature is not visible on image i recommend you to put it on the same place with some other feature and this way you will understand its visibility later

Comment: I want to register five facial images at different angles in a single planar image. This is why I need to create a .dat file that is effective in this regard.
what could be the most effective landamarks for this purpose?

Comment: is your goal to determine face angle? or you simply have several image with different angles on one big picture that you want to annotate? if first - take a look at CLM Framework, that uses dlib internally (https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/CLM-framework). If second - you can simply put all features tah you need on image. when feature is "invisible", you should decide - what output you expect from shape_predictor in a future? if it doesnt matter - skip features from annotation process, if you need them to be in some known place - put them in that place

Comment: I have five photo of the same subject brut with different inclination and i want to put it in a one planar image; i want TO train my dataset with the same 30 features for each image inclination

Comment: i cant understand the idea of putting five images together. why not use them separatelly? each face will be processed separate from each other as on one image, as on severals.

Comment: @Evgeniy @Mehmet I have the i-Bug menpo dataset and `.pts` files but noticed there is no info on the bounding boxes which is present in the `xml` files for dlib.  I emailed i-Bug for this but what other solutions are there for this?

Comment: @mLstudent33, you can generate bounding boxes yourself by reading point positions and looking for min/max X/Y coordinates. better - detect objects and then write coordinate of detections

Answer (score 1):

Evgeniy's answer is useful but when running imglab with --parts argument, numerical labels should be like:

```
imglab --parts "01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12" xml_file_name.xml
```

Otherwise, since dlib sorts the parts by name in xml, labels will be confusing while predicting.